# Vertical placeholder for a nested jQueryUI sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm looking for a way to create a placeholder for sortable that would be:

- Vertical, if the element (`.sortable-cell`) is about to be passed as
  a new cell in a row (`.sortable-row`)
- Horizontal, if the element is about to be passed as a new row (I'm using a wrapper around cell).

The vertical placeholder (`.highlight-vertical`) works fine, now I'm figuring out how to make the horizontal placeholder (`.highlight-horizontal`) work. It needs an if condition for which class to use.

It should occupy the whole row, where the element should be added, right now nothing is being displayed as a horizontal placeholder.

I don't understand the `container` object in the `placeholder` `update` property and how it can be useful in determining what to display.

```js
var sortableParameters = {
  connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
  placeholder: {
    element: function(currentItem) {
      return '<li class="highlight-vertical"></li>';
    },
    update: function(container, p) {
      console.log(container, p);
      //if (container.hasClass('.sortable-grid')) {
      //horizontal placeholder
      //} else {
      //vertical placeholder
      //}
      return;
    }
  },
  start: function(event, ui) {
    sender = $(this);
  },
  over: function(event, ui) {},
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    item = $(ui.item);
    receiver = $(ui.item.parent());

    //Create wrapper around cells passed into new rows
    if (item.hasClass('sortable-cell') && receiver.hasClass('sortable-grid')) {
      item.wrap("<li class='sortable-table'><ul class='sortable-row connectedSortable ui-sortable'></ul></li>").parent().sortable(sortableParameters);
    }

    //Remove empty rows
    if (sender.hasClass('sortable-row') && sender.children().length == 0) {
      sender.parent().remove()
    }
  }
}
$('.sortable-grid, .sortable-row').sortable(sortableParameters);
```

```css
.sortable-grid .sortable-table {
  padding: 3px 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.sortable-grid .sortable-row {
  height: 100%;
  display: table-row;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}
.sortable-grid .sortable-cell {
  background-color:#eeeeee;
  display: table-cell;
  cursor: move;
}
.sortable-grid .highlight-vertical {
  width: 5px;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: blue;
}
.sortable-grid .highlight-horizontal {
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-beta.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul class="sortable-grid connectedSortable">
  <li class="sortable-table">
    <ul class="sortable-row connectedSortable">
      <li class="sortable-cell">Item 1</li>
      <li class="sortable-cell">Item 2</li>
      <li class="sortable-cell">Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sortable-table">
    <ul class="sortable-row connectedSortable">
      <li class="sortable-cell">Item 4</li>
      <li class="sortable-cell">Item 5</li>
      <li class="sortable-cell">Item 6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic switching of the placeholder was achieved by modifying the `update()` function of the placeholder. The function uses parrameters `container` and `placeholder` from which the new container and placeholder jQuery objects can be retrieved.

**Edit:** There is still a bug - when some cells are being dragged to the last (or first) row, the placeholder doesn't appear.

```js
var sortableParameters = {
  connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
  placeholder: {
    element: function(currentItem) {
      return '<li></li>';
    },
    update: function(container, placeholder) {
      if ($(container.element[0]).hasClass('sortable-grid')) {
        placeholder.removeClass('highlight-vertical');
        placeholder.addClass('highlight-horizontal');
        console.log('horizontal placeholder', placeholder);
      } else {
        placeholder.removeClass('highlight-horizontal');
        placeholder.addClass('highlight-vertical');
        console.log('vertical placeholder', placeholder);
      }
      return;
    }
  },
  start: function(event, ui) {
    sender = $(this);
  },
  over: function(event, ui) {},
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    item = $(ui.item);
    receiver = $(ui.item.parent());

    //Create wrapper around cells passed into new rows
    if (item.hasClass('sortable-cell') && receiver.hasClass('sortable-grid')) {
      item.wrap("<li class='sortable-table'><ul class='sortable-row connectedSortable ui-sortable'></ul></li>").parent().sortable(sortableParameters);
    }

    //Remove empty rows
    if (sender.hasClass('sortable-row') && sender.children().length == 0) {
      sender.parent().remove()
    }
  }
}
$('.sortable-grid, .sortable-row').sortable(sortableParameters);
```

```css
.sortable-grid .sortable-table {
  padding: 3px 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.sortable-grid .sortable-row {
  height: 100%;
  display: table-row;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}
.sortable-grid .sortable-cell {
  background-color:#eeeeee;
  display: table-cell;
  cursor: move;
}
.sortable-grid .highlight-vertical {
  width: 5px;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: blue;
}
.sortable-grid .highlight-horizontal {
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-beta.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul class="sortable-grid connectedSortable">
  <li class="sortable-table">
    <ul class="sortable-row connectedSortable">
      <li class="sortable-cell">Item 1</li>
      <li class="sortable-cell">Item 2</li>
      <li class="sortable-cell">Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sortable-table">
    <ul class="sortable-row connectedSortable">
      <li class="sortable-cell">Item 4</li>
      <li class="sortable-cell">Item 5</li>
      <li class="sortable-cell">Item 6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```